# ETL tool migration : Best Practices in Parallel Run

Tags: parallel-processing, etl, data-warehouse, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am new to ETL migration. I have worked with Talend, but not yet faced the task to migrate large ETL project from one tool to another(IBM Data Manager to Informatica PowerCenter or Informatica Developer).

I am looking to general guidlines for migrate jobs from one tool to another one, and of course for my specific case.

I will be more clear:

The Databases Sources and Targes will be the same, what I have to migrate is the ETL part itself.

The approach will be the parallel run as suggested at this blog :

[Parallel Run](http://www.b-eye-network.com/view/13178)

In my case I have not to migrate the all DWH instead only the ETL as the old software will become a legacy one and the new one is from another Vendor(luckly both of them can export XML ).

I am looking for the pratical approch for parallel run, indeed I am been suggested to copy the Sources and Targes Tables in the orginal Database schema, but it does not look to me the best way to go(even not pratical when a schema has many tables).

The DWH I am woking of course has several DBS instance in Oracle and some in SQL Server, a Test server and a Production one, as well as for each, a Staging, Storage and a Data Mart area.

As from this related question and its answer, I am thinking to copy each schema on the go for each project.

[Staging in ETL: Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997776/staging-in-etl-best-practices)

Looking to have guidlines references, but my specific case is the migration from IBM Data Manager to Informatica PowerCenter

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for SO's Q&A format. But here is some general advice. Create a copy of the target db(s). Rebuild ELT, using new software. Run both old and new. Check they produce exactly the same results. Then check again & again. Run in parallel for as long as you can. This increases the odds of catching obscure/infrequent errors.   Migrations can very quickly become extremely complicated. So don't change anything along the way. Upgrades, fixes and new ideas can wait. Make sure you can rollback to the old solution if all goes wrong on migration day. Test rolling back.

Comment: @destination-data I understand SO's Q&A format, but I don't see how my question is not a good fit as I was as specific as I could(I edit it writing the ETL softwares involved). I am not asking for opinions, I am asking for a list of best practices / experience for such complex task(migrating from an ETL to another one, not that common). Your suggestion is all reasonable and that was my first approach, of course cannot be wrote a solution in an answer, but for sure if there is some Senior ETL engineer out there, he/she could give me a road map(but more specific of what I already have in mind)

Comment: If my question isn't good fit for SO's Q&A, then should be teh same for this one I linked and many similar. On the other end what are your suggestion to make my question fit for the Q&A? Thank you

Comment: My thinking is, questions of this type tend to attract list answers (mostly off-site links).  But it is always hard to say exactly where on-topic ends and off-topic starts.  For that reason, I did not vote for the question to be closed (as I might normally).  Because your question is well-written I also decided not to downvote (as I might normally).  Thinking about your migration... it's hard to provide specific advice without a thorough understanding of the systems, processes, teams & skills available.  Migrations fail/succeed based on the amount of prep carried out beforehand.

Comment: @destination-data I understand what you mean and I appreciate you did not proceed as usual. I can say as far I will have more experience about this migration I will update the question, makeing it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The approach depends on various criteria and personal preferences.  Either way you will need to either duplicate parts or all of the source and destination systems.  On one extreme you can use two instances of the entire system.  If you have complex upstream processes that are part of the test, or you have massive numbers of tables and processes, and you have the bandwidth and resources to duplicate your system then this approach may be optimal.

At the other extreme, if any complex processes occur within the ETL tool itself, or you are simply loading tables and need to check they are loaded correctly, then making copies of the tables and pointing your new or old tool to the table copies may be the way to go.  This method is very simple and easy to setup.

Keep in mind this forum is not meant to replace blogs and in-depth tech articles on those techniques.

Comment: I am proceeding with the second approach, so the one less complicate, because so far for my knowledge, projects do not involve complicate ETL process (and the same could be approached differntly with the new one, Informatica), even I simplified as I can manage to extract from source not in the same time of jobs in the old system,so can use same source). I am going with this approach, at least as far I do not have different request.